# Apply rotate transform to tiled background image

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a simple way to render a *rotated* tiled image as a view background? Something to the effect of `UIColor(patternImage:)` but where the image is rotated at a certain angle?

Comment: I've never used the CoreImage filter, but it looks like CIPerspectiveTile is exactly what you want. (I've used CIPerspectiveCorrect along with other CI filters, so if you need code I could help out. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPerspectiveTile

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve here.  Perhaps you could expand your question with some images showing the desired result.

Comment: @dfd You were close! `CIAffineTile` did the trick.

Comment: Glad I pointed you in the good direction. CoreImage, once you use it, does a lot of graphic things well. It's come a long way since iOS 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Core Image filter `CIAffineTile` does exactly what I want.

```
extension UIImage {
    func tile(angle: CGFloat) -> CIImage? {
        return CIImage(image: self)?.applyingFilter(
            "CIAffineTile",
            withInputParameters: [
                kCIInputTransformKey: NSValue(
                    cgAffineTransform: CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
                )
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

This function creates a `CIImage` with infinite extent, which can be cropped and converted to a real image.

```
let v = UIImageView()

// ...

let source = UIImage(named: "sample")!
let tiled = source.tile(angle: CGFloat.pi / 6)!
let result = UIImage(ciImage: tiled.cropping(to: v.bounds))

v.image = result
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to achieve this, at least not in vanilla Swift. I would use another `UIView` as a subview for our original view, set its background to a tiled image and add a `CGAffineTransform` to that particular view.

Comment: You could easily write a UIView extension to do exactly that, and then it would be easy if needed multiple times.

Comment: I considered it, but I don't want a second `UIView` because it'd have to be unnecessarily large if I want to cover my view completely.